# Rails 3.2 - Would sending a POST request from a client application pose any security risks?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, authentication, post, request

I am planning on creating a client application in .NET that would send an HTTP POST request to my Rails application in order to update a given value in a database table. I'm using PostgreSQL as a database for my Rails app. As part of the POST request, I would need to send parameters with the URL to specify the information I'd like to update. Rails would then process the parameters and update the correct information in the database.

I feel that this could easily be a security risk since it seems that anyone could theoretically send a POST request with different parameters to modify the database. I know Rails has authentication tokens built into POST requests, so my intuition would be that my .NET requests would be rejected.

I was wondering if anyone could provide me with a little more insight on this topic. Would my requests be accepted by Rails, and if so, what protections might be in place to stop anyone from making a POST request to the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the POST do/contain? A client is, after all, a client and most (if not all) of the same attack vectors apply. (You'd also have to setup the correct authentication in the .NET requests; if any unauthorized request is allowed where it should not be, then the app is broken independent of this question.)

Comment: As an example, my database table has two columns: Word (VARCHAR) and Count (INT). Word would be a word in the english dictionary, and Count is the number of times the word has been entered by all users. The user would type in a word and perform some action, and then the Count value for the specified word would be incremented by 1.

Therefore, the information that would be sent through the POST is just the word. The Count could be obtained and updated in Rails itself.

Comment: So is it "bad" if any user spams the service? If an authenticated user spams the service? (That is, even though nothing "dangerous" is inherently done, it could still lead to "poisoning".)

Comment: I would say yes because this service is relatively important for the application's usage. Under normal use, it wouldn't be possible for anyone to spam the service since it uploads the "word" only once, and after that the user cannot enter another word again.

Comment: Then don't let users (from any source) spam the service :) Require the .NET clients to also authenticate and treat a (any) client request as a (any) client request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your rails app will accept the post if you have your routes.rb file setup correctly.

What you are really asking is "How do a create a save/secure API in my rails app?"

I have done this quite a bit and what we do is have some kind of authentication process. This may be a shared key (base plus some semi random portion) that is encrypted during transmission, or an actual sign in process.

My suggestion is to have a shared key that you encrypt and include in your POST header. You can retrieve it with something like

```
token = request.env['HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN']
```

then just decrypt it and verify the semi random portion before accepting the POST

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight! This certainly gets me on the right track. I have one question, though. How would Rails know what the semi-random part is if I generated it in .NET? I would assume that I would generate the semi-random part in .NET, send it through to Rails, and then Rails would decrypt it, but how would Rails verify the semi-random part in this case?